# 'ImportError: No module named pillow' in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pycharm

I'm getting an error while using PyCharm which doesn't allow me to import the pillow module even though I have it installed as a package in the project interpreter. Any help is greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C7DO.jpg

Comment: Is the version of python running the script same as the one which you have installed the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, version 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the name of the package is pillow, it is a replacement for PIL and uses the PIL for the name of the base module

the usual way to use pillow is

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("filename")
```

See the [tutorial](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html), and the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/index.html)

Comment: One might note that PyCharm still seems to flag this because PIL wouldn't be listed in the project requirements.txt...

Answer (score 0):

You try to run code with default Python interpreter (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3`). You need to configure PyCharm to run Your code with anaconda (`~/anaconda/bin/python`)

And now (Like @JamesK say) read Pillow tutorial and documentation:

`import PIL` not `import Pillow`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just tried that but it still seems to not be working. http://imgur.com/a/LZ1Eq

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still having trouble with this, I did the following which solved my problem.

1. Open up your Project Interpreter (⌘ + , on Mac).
2. At the bottom of this page you'll see the + symbol to the left of the anaconda logo. This will create a pop-up that allows you to search for available packages.
3. In this new window, search for 'Pillow'.
4. Click and Install Package.

You should now be able to use "from PIL import Image" or "import Pillow as pil" etc.

Answer (score 0):

After running this command on your terminal

```py
pip install pillow
```

and you are sure it was installed, but still having same problem of PIL module not found.

Go to your  IDE and make sure existing interpreter is set to python interpreter and not anaconda