# Successful install of Python wheel file but module not found

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-wheel

I created a wheel file from my Python source files using pyproject.toml and setup.cfg without any issue.

```
python3 -m build
```

The files are available on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/zsiki/ulyxes/tree/master/pyapi
```

I copied the created wheel file to another machine for testing and installed the package from the wheel file successfully:

```
sudo pip3 install ulyxes-0.0.1.-py3-none-any.whl
```

The package files are installed in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ulyxes-0.0.1.dist-info
```

The Python source files are in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

When I try to import my package I get an error

```
>>> import ulyxes
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ulyxes'
```

The Python path contains the package directory:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

How can I access my package?

### UPDATE

I forget to mention that I can find the package by pip3:

```
pip3 list | grep ulyxes
ulyxes                       0.0.1
```

Comment: What result do you get for `which pip3`? What result do you get for `which python3`?

Comment: `ulyxes-0.0.1.dist-info` is metadata. Your package files are not in there.

Comment: Also: installing something named `ulyxes` - whether by PyPI, from a cached `.whl` file, or any other way - **does not** necessarily imply that you will be able to import a package with the same name `ulyxes`. You should [read the documentation](https://github.com/zsiki/ulyxes/blob/master/doc/Ulyxes_user_doc.rst#pyapi-tutorials) in order to understand how to use the code. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194601 for one of the more common examples of this issue.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The OP seems to be one of the authors of this project, so they *should* know how to use it... which makes it kind of weird that they're trying to `import ulyxes`. Looking at the repository, particularly `setup.cfg`, I think they've gotten confused and overwhelmed by the complexity of Python packaging.

Comment: It doesn't help that "package" means two completely different things.

Comment: You know, it *does*. That doesn't often occur to me. I'm not completely sure the dev team has realized it either.

Comment: @user2357112 as I wrote you the files of the package are in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel that documentation was written by me :(

Comment: @Karl Knechtel 'which python3' is '/usr/bin/python3'.

Comment: "Package" in the sense of the things that `pip list` lists and "package" in the sense of things you import are two completely different things, despite the same word being used for both. (It's confusing.) The fact that you've installed a "package" named `ulyxes` doesn't mean you can import a "package" named `ulyxes`, because those are two different meanings of "package".

Comment: @user2357112 OK. What should I do?

Comment: You've got files in `/usr/local/bin`, but that's not where they're supposed to go. That's where command-line utilities go, not importable modules. They're there because you listed them under `scripts` in `setup.cfg`. The correct fix depends on the interface you want your code to have.

Comment: You tried to `import ulyxes`. Is that how you *want* your code to work, or just how you thought it had to work? The examples in your documentation show your code being used as a bunch of top-level modules. Having everything grouped under a `ulyxes` package (in the import sense) is cleaner and less prone to name collision than having a giant pile of top-level modules, but it also breaks backward compatibility with what seems to be the existing usage.

Comment: I changed the setup.cfg (updated on GitHub) and moved one level upper in the directory structure (pyproject.toml too). Import now works e.g "from ulyxes.angle import Angle" but the internal imports are broken. I would like to maintain the non package usage for developers and pip install for end users. Is it possible?

Comment: Changing imports to relative in the Python files of the package (e.g. from .angle import Angle) helps to use them from the package but breaks using them in developing environment. How other projects solve this?

Comment: Other projects solve this by being consistent about whether something is a package submodule or a top-level package. Trying to have it both ways is a huge mess.

Comment: Still cannot "hello world" with pyproject really awful